# Why does this piece of code have this edge case

Tags: python

I was trying to try a palindrome test but a specific number 10022201, always returns true.

```
class Solution():
    def isPalindrome(x):
        if isinstance(x, int):
            x = str(x)
        for y in x:
            index = x.index(y)
            rev = x[::-1]
            if x[index] != rev[index]:
                b = bool(0)
                break
            else:
                b = bool(1)
        return b                
x = 10022201
solution = Solution()
result = Solution.isPalindrome(x)
print(result)
```

help please!

Comment: And if you add this the problem goes away.                                                                                                                    
```                                                                                                                                             
if x == 10022201:                                                                                                              
    x+=1                                                                                                                                ```

Comment: If you go to the bother of calculating `rev = x[::-1]` then you only need `return x == rev`

Comment: @slothrop that's the answer. I'd lightly encourage you to post it as an answer to collect your deserved upvote and checkmark points. Could even suggest solutions like using `for index, y in enumerate(x)` in the loop to get the index more correctly/reliably/efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `x.index(y)`, it returns the *first* value in `x` that matches `y`. Therefore, when you're on the second zero, it returns the index of the first zero.

What you can do instead is this:

```py
class Solution():
    def isPalindrome(x):
        if isinstance(x, int):
            x = str(x)
        for index in range(len(x)):
            rev = x[::-1]
            if x[index] != rev[index]:
                b = bool(0)
                break
            else:
                b = bool(1)
        return b
```

Here, you go through all the possible indeces in the string, and then you check if each corresponding character is equivalent. Basically what you were trying to do, just simplified.

Also, you can just check for string equality, comparing the string of the number to the reversed version of that:

```py
class Solution():
    def isPalindrome(x):
        if isinstance(x, int):
            x = str(x)
        rev = x[::-1] 
        return x == rev
```

Comment: You have my upvote for first presenting code which has the fewest changes to fix the problem, plus an alternate which sweeps away most of the other underlying problems.

Comment: @Nickistired couldn't one also just run `x = str(x)` straight up, rather than checking with the `if`?

Comment: @KellyBundy Right!, I now understand. *"if x isn't a string, then your `rev = str(x)[::-1]` doesn't suffice, as `x == rev` will fail"* just didn't click the first time you said it, the rephrase helped, appreciate the patience. My suggestion would've made sense as `return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]`, but that's a bit... unsightly.

Comment: @Nickistired Yeah, I might even do that `str(x) == str(x)[::-1]`, although I dislike it.